Cannot find module 'cookie-parser' when building NestJS with Webpack
I'm encountering an issue while trying to build my NestJS application using Webpack. When I attempt to run the application after the build process, I get the following error:
Error: Cannot find module 'cookie-parser'

Here's my webpack configuration:
const path = require('path');
const { IgnorePlugin } = require('webpack');
const {
  swcDefaultsFactory,
} = require('@nestjs/cli/lib/compiler/defaults/swc-defaults');
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");


dotenv.config();


/** @type { import('webpack').Configuration } */
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main',
  externals: {},
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'swc-loader',
          options: swcDefaultsFactory().swcOptions,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false,
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
  },
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
            './node_modules/cookie-parser/index.js',
            './node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui.css',
            './node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui.js',
            './node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js',
            './node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/favicon-16x16.png',
            './node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/favicon-32x32.png'
        ]
    }),
    new IgnorePlugin({
      checkResource(resource) {
        const lazyImports = [
            '@fastify/static',
            '@fastify/view',
            '@nestjs/microservices',
            '@nestjs/microservices/microservices-module',
            '@nestjs/platform-express',
            '@nestjs/websockets/socket-module',
            'amqp-connection-manager',
            'amqplib',
            'cache-manager',
            'cache-manager/package.json',
            'class-transformer/storage',
            'hbs',
            'ioredis',
            'kafkajs',
            'mqtt',
            'nats',
            'compression',
          ];
        if (!lazyImports.includes(resource)) {
          return false;
        }
        try {
          require.resolve(resource, { paths: [process.cwd()] });
        } catch (err) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      },
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.ts'],
    mainFields: ['main'],
    plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({ configFile: 'tsconfig.json' })],
  },
  target: 'node',
};

I've already installed 'cookie-parser' via npm, and it's listed in my package.json as a dependency. The application runs fine without any issues when I'm not using webpack.
Could anyone suggest what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

does it works when compiling with tsc?

i confuse, when i use swc-loader the bundle it not working
i change from swc-loader to ts-loader
